# Уникальность в random

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть набор вопросов. Как сделать так, чтобы они не повторялись?

```
while True:
    question = random.choice(list(storage.keys()))
    print(question, end=' ')
    user_answer = input()

    # Проверяем ответ. Если правильный, то начисляется +1 балл. Регистр не имеет значение.
    if user_answer.lower() == storage[question].lower():
        point += 1
        print('\tВерно! У Вас', point, 'балла.')
```

Comment: добавить после question = random.choice(list(storage.keys())) -> del storage[key], в таком случае вопросы удаляются и повторов точно не будет

Comment: также можно добавить еще один ключ для проверки т\ф, если т оставлять, если ф искать пока не найдет т

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы удалить ключ независимо от того, находится ли он в словаре, используйте форму `dict.pop()` с двумя аргументами:

```
storage.pop('key', None)
```

Чтобы удалить ключ, который гарантированно существует, вы также можете использовать

```
del storage['key']
```

---

```
from random import choice

storage = {"Вопрос 1": "...",
           "Вопрос 2": "...",
           "Вопрос 3": "...",
           "Вопрос 4": "...",}

while storage:
    question = choice(list(storage.keys()))
    print(question, end=' ')
    user_answer = input()

    if user_answer.lower() == storage[question].lower():
        point += 1
        print('\tВерно! У Вас', point, 'балла.')
    storage.pop(question, None)
```

Comment: Спасибо, благодарю.